# Aggregation relationship in class diagram

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mapping-class-groups, string-diagrams, diagram-chase, relation-algebra

How do you transform an aggregation relatinship between to classes in a class diagram (1 to many or many to many) into relational schema and is it needed/possible. Or is enough if we transform only their either one to one or one to many relationship. Shortly, do we have an aggregation relationship from class diagram transformed in relational schema?